# Use PHP to increment number for image ID

Tags: php, html, image, numbers

So, I have a problem in that I have 67 (and counting) images all named IMAGE01.jpg, IMAGE02.jpg all the way to IMAGE67.jpg.

In my HTML page, I have this code to display the image.

```
<article class="thumb">
                        <a href="images/fulls/image01.jpg" class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/image01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</article>
```

So, I have this for 67 images. Is there a way of incrementing the image number using PHP? So I can just copy and paste that piece of code for the number of images I have?

That's the first part that would be GREAT to have a solution too. But, would there be a way to not have to repeat that code for every image? Would it be possible to use PHP to define the number of times I want this to be repeated?

So have the snippet of code once and have something to repeat it a defined number of times so as I add to the collection, all I have to do is change the repeat times?

Many thanks in advance for the help. Means allot.

Comment: your looking for a `for` loop ... hint search google "php for loop"

Comment: A `while` loop could also be used. Users preferences for which loop to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    for($i=1; $i<=67; $i++) {
?>
<article class="thumb">
    <a href="images/fulls/image<?php
        if($i<9)
            echo "0".$i;
        else
            echo $i;
    ?>.jpg" class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/image<?php
        if($i<9)
            echo "0".$i;
        else
            echo $i;
    ?>.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</article>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Its quite evident from the answer why should OP use try this!

Comment: Keep in mind that new programmers and other visitors will come here, find this and *have no idea* what you did or why you did it. Without an explanation and being a code only answer it is likely to get deleted by the community and will not likely earn many, if any, votes. When you were a new programmer would you have understood this without explanation?

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work? Any ideas why? I can see what it is trying to do, and it is trying to do it, but no result.

Answer (score 2):

To make what you want you need to use a for loop from 1 to 67 (because your image name are from 1 to 67). And for each iteration you have to echo the html string.

Like this for example :

```
for($i = 1; $i<=67; $i++){
    $name = $i<10?"0".$i:$i;
    echo "<article class='thumb'>
        <a href='images/fulls/image".$name.".jpg' class='image'>
            <img src='images/thumbs/image".$name.".jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>
    </article>";
}
```

You need to construct the name if the name need to have 0 before (01, 02 ...). It's what I make here :`$name = $i<10?"0".$i:$i;`. It's mean that if $i < 10 then we add a "0" before else the name is $i.

You can also use a while loop :

```
$i = 1;
while($i<=67){
    $name = $i<10?"0".$i:$i;
    echo "<article class='thumb'>
        <a href='images/fulls/image".$name.".jpg' class='image'>
            <img src='images/thumbs/image".$name.".jpg' alt=''/>
        </a>
    </article>";
    $i++;
}
```

It's the same idea.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PHP variable and inject it into your HTML. The following code will count from 1 - 67.

```
<?php
$count = 1;

while($count <= 67){
?>
<p>Count: <?php echo $count; ?></p>
<?php
    $count +=1;
}
?>
```

So you could use it as such:

```
<article class="thumb">
<?php
$count = 1;

while($count <= $numOfImages){
?>
    <a href="images/fulls/image<?php echo $count; ?>.jpg" class="image"><img src="images/thumbs/image<?php echo $count; ?>.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<?php
    $count +=1;
}
?>
</article>
```

Just set `$numOfImages` to however many images there are and it should work.

Comment: Your code leaves out leading zeros (`01`, `02`), and starts with 0 (the OP starts with 01). You'll only show 66 images, not 67.

Comment: It starts at 1, hence why `$count` is one. But I did forget about the 0's. Some simple logic that OP can take from any above answer. It will also run to 67, or whatever number OP wants. The `<=` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this sample code below if images are one after the other. Using single for loop with printf inside echo...

<body>

<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 67; $i++) {

?>

<article class="thumb">
<a href="images/full/image<?php printf("%02d\n", $i)?>.jpg" ><img src="images/thumb/image<?php printf("%02d\n", $i)?>.png" alt="" /></a>
</article>

<?php
}
?>
</body>

Here is the sample output I kept only one image for testing.     https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Lo5.png
```